# database changes made after a running a JUnit test are not visible

Tags: java, database, spring, junit

I am confronting with the following issue.

I am using Spring with JUnit and an Oracle database.

My tests are marked with `@Transactional` annotation.

When I run a test that does some inserts and I put a breakpoint somewhere at the end of it, if I go into my database and look after those changes, they are not there.

Is there any reason why is this happening?

What am I really doing there is that I have a `batchUpdate()` that inserts all my entries. When the batch finishes, I have a few asserts to test for the data I just added. In this case the test passes. Putting a breakpoint on one of the asserts and going into my database and trying to look after that data won't give me anything.

My tests are configured to run with this database because without `@Transactional` annotation the data is visible inside my tables in the db.

I hope I made myself clear enough.

Comment: Well of course not, first off all changes are only visible to the transaction UNTIL the moment the commit is processed, when you add a breakpoint nothing has been committed and the data is not visible to the outside world. Next to that when using Spring for testing (and extending one of the spring support classes) the data will be even rollback after the test method as to not pollute your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Transactional start a transaction when a method is triggered. A transaction mean operation performed in transaction are not visible by other transaction and are not apply on the database until commit.
The commit will occured after the execution of you method so that's why you can't see any update if you break point in the middle of the execution.

Please read about how [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) work .

Comment: Is there any way to make this possible? I want my tests to be transactional so that there won't be garbage data but I would also like to see the data in my database when debugging my tests. Actually this was the purpose of my question.

Comment: To my knowledge it's not possible. What you can do is to configure your logger to log orm sql debug.